# Highcharts: how to align column and line chart x-axises

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have 2 Highchart charts: column chart and point chart.

They share same xAxis config:

```
{
    type: 'datetime',
    min: Date.UTC(2010, 01, 02),
    max: Date.UTC(2010, 01, 14),
    startOnTick: true,
}
```

I want to **align their x axises** so values on corresponding dates are located on same **vertical** line.

How can I modify charts so that their x axises are properly aligned?

#### jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vmdLommk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is caused by automatically applied padding to the axis for a column series, to account for the width of the column itself.

There are probably multiple things that can be done, but I find it easiest to manage this way:

Add a dummy column series to your line chart. This will force the same kind of padding that is applied to the column chart.

Example:

```
{
  name: 'dummy',
  showInLegend: false,
  type: 'column'
}
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/vmdLommk/2/